# CCLabelBMFont, Encodings and Special characters

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Ok, I give up... (I am using cocos2d-x in an iOS env for now)

I am building a game, where I have to read strings (potentially German, French, etc.) from a text file and display them in labels.

I started, using standard ifstream to read the file and everything worked fine for pure english text. When I tried german (containing umlauts) however, the app fails on

```
CCAssert( c < kCCBMFontMaxChars, "LabelBMFont: character outside bounds");
```

c in this case might equal to 65468, which is definitely not a character I want to display.

So following another hint I changed the preceding line in CCLabelBMFont.cpp to

```
unsigned long c = m_sString[i];
```

from
    unsigned short c = m_sString[i];
which causes the Assert to not fail anymore but still produces garbled output.

So I tinkered a bit with abandoning ifstream and using Cocoa methods to read the file. After some trial and error I found that combining the above fix with the following method of reading the file actually did the trick

```
NSString *readString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithCString:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
std::string cc2dxString ([readString cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
```

...until I tried the same thing with a French file (containing accented characters), which produced garbled output again.

Since this solution was ugly to begin with I now feel the need to ask: Am I doing it completely wrong or is there actually some inherent flaw in cocos2d-x's implementation of CCLabelBMFont?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, CCLabelBMFont was indeed the problem.

You can get a version with full UTF-8 support from their github repository

Comment: How would I replace an if test like this: `for(NSUInteger i=0; i<[m length]; i++) {
  unichar c = [m characterAtIndex:i];
  if(c >= kCCBMFontMaxChars) { 
   m = [m stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:@"'"];
  }
 }`

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to ask here. Right now you are replacing unsupported characters with apostrophes. What do you want to do?

Comment: kCCBMFontMaxChars returns a warning in cocos2d v2.0. i think it was deprecated. so how would i replace it in that if test?